# Is vegan::cca() treating each possible value of a categorical environmental variable as a separate factor?

Tags: r, vegan

I am applying canonical correspondence analysis to a dataset of herbaceous plant species presence in 48 quadrats arranged across a large forested area, where environmental variables for each quadrat include both continuous (% cover of tree canopy above the quadrat) and categorical (microtopography, with possible values of bowl, slope, ridge, and level) variables. When plotting the CCA, I notice that all possible values of the categorical variable are plotted, while only the name of the single continuous variable is plotted (figure below). Does this indicate that function `cca()` is treating each possible value of the categorical variable as a distinct factor, rather than levels of a single factor?

```
cca1 <- cca(formula = quadrats_df ~ canopy_cover + microtopography, data = sitedesc_df, scale = -3)

plot(cca1, type = "text", display = c("sites","cn"))
```

Where `quadrats_df` contains quadrat-level vegetation data, and `sitedesc_df` contains quadrat-level environmental data.

Plotting `cca1` yields the figure below.

[image: Canonical correspondence analysis of vegetation data including continuous and categorical variables as factors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer - no, there is no error and `cca()` is correctly treating possible values of microtopography as levels of a single factor.

From ter Braak and Verdonschot 1995:

- "A CCA ordination diagram may consist of the following elements: points for species, sites, and classes of qualitative environmental variables, and arrows for quantitative environmental variables" (page 265).
- "A qualitative environmental variable consists of a number of classes that partition the sites; *each class is naturally represented by a point on the diagram, namely the centroid of the sites points belonging to the class*" (page 268).

Reference:
Ter Braak, C.J. and Verdonschot, P.F., 1995. Canonical correspondence analysis and related multivariate methods in aquatic ecology. Aquatic sciences, 57(3), pp.255-289.

Comment: This is correct answer. This is the way factors are handled, not only in vegan and CANOCO, but also in functions for linear models (`lm`, `glm` etc).